# How to build a price comparison program that scrapes the prices of a product across several websites

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to build a price comparison program for personal use (and for practice) that allows me to compare prices of the same item across different websites. I have just started using the Scrapy library and played around by scraping websites. These are my steps whenever I scrape a new website:

1) Find the website's search url, understand its pattern, and store it. For instance, Target's search url is composed by a fixed url="https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=" plus the search terms (in parsed url)

2)Once I know the website's search url, I send a SplashRequest using the Splash library. I do this because many pages are heavily loaded with JS

3)Look up the HTML structure of the results page and determine the correct xpath expression to parse the prices. However, many websites have results page in different formats depending on the search terms or product category, changing thus the page's HTML code. Therefore, I have to examine all the possible results page's formats and come up with an xpath that can account for all the different formats

I find this process to be very inefficient, slow, and inaccurate. For instance, at step 3, even though I have the correct xpath, I am still unable to scrape all the prices in the page (sometimes I also get prices of items that are not present in the HTML rendered page), which I dont understand. Also, I dont know whether the websites know that my requests come from a bot, thus maybe sending me a faulty or incorrect HTML code. Moreover, this process cannot be automated. For example, I have to repeat step 1 and 2 for every new website. Therefore, I was wondering if there was a more efficient process, library, or approach that I could use to help me finish this program. I also heard something about using the website's API, although I dont quite understand how it works. This is my first time doing scraping and I dont know too much about web technologies, so any help/advice is highly appreciate!

Comment: while interesting, this Q is off-topic for StackOverflow. We're here to help you fix your existing code, not give you a tutorial on webscraping options (sorry). Please read [help] and especially [mcve] before posting more Qs here. I would search for a book that covers this topic. Good luck.

Comment: You probably do not like that answer but - if creating a price comparison engine is not your core business - your best bet is to buy that data from a vendor and consume their API. Having somewhat accurate real-time price comparison data is hard (speaking from my own experience.)

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem with crawling is that in general, they are determining everything to be scraped syntactically, while conceptualizing the entities you are to be working with helps a lot, I am speaking from my own experience.

In a research about scraping I was involved in we have reached to the conclusion that we need to use a [semantic tree](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212017315001206). This tree should contain nodes, which represent important data for your purpose and a parent-child relation means that the parent encapsulates the child in the HTML, XML or other hierarchical structure.

You will therefore need some kind of concept about how you will want to represent the semantic tree and how it will be mapped with site structures. If your search method allows you to use the logical OR, then you will be able to define the same semantic tree for multiple online sources.

On the other hand, if the owners of some sites are willing to allow you to scrape their data, then you might ask them to define the semantic tree.

If a given website's structure is changed, then using a semantic tree more often than not you will be able to comply to the change by just changing the selector of a few elements, if the semantic tree's node structure remains the same. If some owners are partners in allowing scraping, then you will be able to just download their semantic trees.

If a website provides an API, then you can use that, read about REST APIs to do so. However, these APIs are probably not uniform.